Send the image created on canvas to the backend server
I have canvas and for now, i downloaded jpg file with this.
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = ref_canvas_release.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);
 
 a.download = GlobalParam.fileObj.project_name + '.jpg';
 a.click();

then now I want to upload this image to backend instead of download.
So, what I want to do is like this,
    fileimage = ref_canvas_release.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);
    const formData = new FormData();

    //It's not correct.
    formData.append("myfile",fileimage);
    
    var url = '/get_thumbnail';
    axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }).then((res) =>{
        console.log(res);
    });

maybe I don't need to make file but use bytestream,
However how can I do this?

For that you will need to use toBlob method, so we can create a new image file from blob easily.
ref_canvas_release.current.toBlob((blob) => {
       
        const file = new File([blob], "canvas.jpeg",{type:"image/jpeg"});

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('myfile', file);

        let url = '/get_thumbnail';
        axios
            .post(url, formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    },
    'image/jpeg',
    0.85
);

MDN Docs

Thankyou it works perfectly for my purpose, blob call back is difficult to understand, but it worth it.
